# Thread safety when returning static variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, thread-safety, uikit

I'm implementing what is essentially a "Theme" for an iOS application. The theme is known at compile time and will *never* need to be changed/reloaded at runtime.

I've created a `Theme` class who's job will be to vend the appropriate `UIColor` object for the current theme. Relevant parts of the class look like:

Theme.h:

```
 +(UIColor*)primaryColor;
```

Theme.m

```
static UIColor *primaryColor;

//only ever called once, during +[Theme initialize]
+(void)configureColors{ 
    primaryColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}

+(UIColor*)primaryColor{
    return primaryColor;
}
```

Note that the final implementation of `+configureColors` will contain an if test to set a different color based on the desired theme

Do I need to worry about thread safety in this situation? Is there a better way to do it? 
I'm worried that 2 calls could be made to `+primaryColor` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a million concurrent calls to `primaryColor` and not have an issue (other than too many threads :) ). It's a read-only method.

The only possible concern is if `primaryColor` is called at the same time as `configureColors`. And that's not a problem since you are calling `configureColors` from the standard `initialize` method.

And on top of all of that, you will most likely be calling `primaryColor` from the main thread since you are likely dealing with UI updates.